How to include a .xsd when we provide a soap webservice via a spring boot app
I followed How to use WSDL with spring-boot?
to create a soap webservice in a spring boot app. Here they have used to provide webservice(Note: We already have a wsdl file.)
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    //http://localhost:8080/ws/services.wsdl --bean name is set to 'services'
    @Bean(name = "services")
    public Wsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/schema/MyWsdl.wsdl")); //your wsdl location
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
}

My question is that my wsdl has references to some other .xsd files like CommonHeader.xsd. So when I try to import it in soap ui I get the error
Error loading [http://localhost:8080/app/CommonHeader.xsd]
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Premature end of file

I want to provide webservice to the users.
